# How to manage Numpy arrays in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's assume one has a DataFrame with some integers values and some arrays defined somehow:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 1)), columns=['rand_int'])
array_a = np.arange(5) 
array_b = np.arange(7)
df['array_a'] = df['rand_int'].apply(lambda x: array_a[:x])
df['array_b'] = df['rand_int'].apply(lambda x: array_b[:x])
```

Some questions which can help me understand how to manage Numpy arrays with Pandas DataFrames:

1. How can one define array_a and array_b columns in df as the product between the item in the n-th row in column rand_int?
2. Is it possible to create another column, let's name it `array_diff`, which is the np.setdiff1d between array_a and array_b for each row?

Comment: So you want to multiply both array a and array b by the corresponding value in rand_int?

Comment: Not only that, but also define another column in `df` which is the `np.setdiff1d` between the rows in `array_a` and `array_b`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's better to work with NumPy and import data into the dataframe as a last step.

Anyway here's a solution that stores arrays into the dataframe step by step. Not really sure you actually want the outer product, it would be great if you could post the expected result.

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 1)), columns=['rand_int']) 
>>> df
   rand_int
0        51
1        92
2        14
3        71
4        60

df['a'] = np.split(np.outer(df['rand_int'], np.arange(5)), 5) 
df['b'] = np.split(np.outer(df['rand_int'], np.arange(7)), 5)

>>> df
   rand_int                         a                                   b
0        51  [[0, 51, 102, 153, 204]]  [[0, 51, 102, 153, 204, 255, 306]]
1        92  [[0, 92, 184, 276, 368]]  [[0, 92, 184, 276, 368, 460, 552]]
2        14     [[0, 14, 28, 42, 56]]       [[0, 14, 28, 42, 56, 70, 84]]
3        71  [[0, 71, 142, 213, 284]]  [[0, 71, 142, 213, 284, 355, 426]]
4        60  [[0, 60, 120, 180, 240]]  [[0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360]]

df['d'] = df.b.combine(df.a, func=np.setdiff1d)
>>> df['d']
0    [255, 306]
1    [460, 552]
2      [70, 84]
3    [355, 426]
4    [300, 360]
Name: d, dtype: object
```

Note that `np.split` leaves an extra dimension, not sure if this can be avoided. You might want to remove it with `np.squeeze`

```
>>> df['a'].apply(np.squeeze)
0    [0, 51, 102, 153, 204]
1    [0, 92, 184, 276, 368]
2       [0, 14, 28, 42, 56]
3    [0, 71, 142, 213, 284]
4    [0, 60, 120, 180, 240]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Really helpful thanks! This addresses my need. Unfortunately I did not get the notification, apologize for the late reply.